# What to log, php webservice

Tags: php, logging

I'm creating an PHP webapplication.

My company gets data and via a webapplication we present it to our customers. 
Thats the main goal of the webapplication, presenting data. Besides that users can change and add some data, buts that not the focus of the application.

Each user has its own database.

Now I was wondering what should I log?
A friend of me said that I could log query errors, like

```
mysql_query($sql);
if((mysql_error()) {
  //log something
}
```

Another said me to store the logins in the db.

Can someone provide me some advice what to log and what not to log?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very vague question. You have to log what may come in handy later.

Comment: _Each user has its own database._ - how many users are you expecting? May want to rethink this one

Comment: @AaronW.I'm not expecting hundreds of users.

Comment: @mobius are there not things that you always log when creating a system of service?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Monolog or Log4PHP. There are other similars.